# Ubuntu 18.04 is not booting after uninstalling Windows 10 from dual boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So I have an Acer Aspire E5, laptop which came with Windows 10.

I installed Ubuntu 18 on it as Dual boot.

Now running out of disk space I tried to remove Windows 10.  However now I am unable to boot into Ubuntu.

Summary of what I did.

Used Ubuntu live USB then used GParted / OS-Uninstaller to remove Windows 10.  Deleted the Windows 10 partition and also EFI/boot partitions after having lots of problems.  I used boot-repair to repair my boot.  The paste-bin of log with an error "Unknown Boot-loader" is here:

[boot-repair output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HRFMdqZ4MQ/)

Finally my partitions looks like this as seen from GParted on live USB:

[image: GParted]

Now when I boot I get the grub options:

[image: grub screenshot]

However at the end I get the following and am unable to boot:

"You are in emergency mode.."

[image: Unable to boot, emergency mode]

The good thing is that all my data is still there, which I can see from a Ubuntu live USB which mounts the laptop drive.

So I do not Windows but maybe removing the EFI/boot partition caused this issue. Also Boot-Repair wants me to boot with UEFI mode (and not legacy).  So can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Modern PCs have 2 boot options, UEFI or Legacy. You likely installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode and have deleted the EFI partition. This means now Ubuntu can't boot.

Sounds like you need to rebuild the EFI partition. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Your data is still there, but you just can't load it. The partition has a boot flag. Likely, you Ubuntu partition does not.

Take a look at this section of the article referenced above. 
Creating an EFI System Partition

Each install is different, so I don't have an exact answer, but I bet you just need a new EFI partition with appropriate flags and repaired to contain the correct EFI files.

Also, see here:
Converting Ubuntu into UEFI mode